# backbone epoxy.js with underscore text template

Tags: backbone.js

Does anyone have pointers for using Backbone.Epoxy ( epoxy.js ) with HTML passed in via template.

aka given a View such as

```
define([
   'jquery',
   'underscore',
   'backbone',
   'epoxy',
   'text!views/MyTemplate.html'

], function($, _, Backbone, Epoxy, Template ){

var MyView = Epoxy.View.extend({

      template: _.template(Template),

      bindings: {
         ".brand-name": "text:name",      
         ".brand-name": "text:count",
      },

      // Perhaps render not needed given that epoxy bindings  
      render : function() {
         var data = {
           item: this.model,
          _: _ 
         };
         this.$el.html( this.template(data) );
         return this;
    }

  return MyView;

});
```

which renders the template but without any bindings.

and does one need a render method anymore..!

Comment: it appears that Backbones 'el'  may be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need the render method, just instantiate you view.

```
var view = new BindingView({model: bindModel});
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/D7w8S/)

But when you use the render method and replace the view.el you lost those bindings, in that case try to do :

```
this.$el.html( this.template(data) );
this.applyBindings();
```

Comment: thanks. in that case, the backbone/epoxy code is merged with the html. im referring to the case where html is passed in via 'text!views/MyTemplate.html'